# Can not chage angular $scope with ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to change directive controller's $scope with ng-click.

I have one simple button:

```
<button ng-click="showEnterKeyField = !showEnterKeyField">btn {{showEnterKeyField}}</button>
```

This code works. I mean, we will se something like ( as button **.text()** ):

```
btn true
btn false
btn true
... etc
```

But in controller we have:

```
$scope.$watch('showEnterKeyField', function(val) {
    console.log(val);
}, true);
```

And in console there are no logs at all.

Next thing that I was thying to do is to run some `test()` fn inside of `ng-click`:

```
<button ng-click="test()">btn {{showEnterKeyField}}</button>
```

And for my surprise this code works exactly same as above one:

```
btn true
btn false
btn true
... etc
```

This time i see records in the console.

Why does the scope is not changing in the first scenario? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Of course, here is my `$scope.test()`:

```
$scope.test = function() {
    $scope.showEnterKeyField = !$scope.showEnterKeyField;
};
```

Comment: what your test function does? something like $scope.showEnterKeyField = !$scope.showEnterKeyField?

Comment: is your directive inheriting, creating or sharing a scope?

Comment: works fine:[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s39rY/1/) . Just set initial value for you variable

Comment: Here directive's return value return {
 restrict: 'E',
 replace: true,
 link: link,
 scope: {
  module: '='
 },
 templateUrl: '..url here...',
 controller: controller
};

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the attribute (in this case `showEnterKeyField`) on you controllers scope first, so it will be inherited by the ngClick directive. If it's not defined, the **ngClick directive will create the attribute on it's own child scope** - so you cannot watch it from within your controllers (parent) scope.

Simply add the following to your controller:

```
$scope.showEnterKeyField = false; // or some other initial value
```

See: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/veceq/1/edit)